# Loop over specific column in dataframe and output to different column in R

Tags: r, loops

Currently trying to add a column in a dataframe where it takes into account a different column (date) where it determines if the information is historical or a forecast based on a variable (upload date).

Here's how I see it in pseudocode:
If the upload date is greater than or equal to the date in the date column -> the corresponding column will be populated with 'historical'
else the corresponding column will be populated with 'forecast'

Obviously, I'm fairly new to R so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Based on updates, here's where it stands now:

```
table_dates <- all$TimePeriod
str(table_dates)
table_output <- data.frame(date = table_dates)
str(table_output)

table_output <-
  table_output %>% 
  mutate(upload = if_else(date < upload_date, "Actual","forecast"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `dplyr::mutate()` function. The following code should have the effect that you're looking for.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

x <- c(date("2017-1-1"), date("2019-1-1"))
upload_date <- today()

df <- data.frame(date = x)

df <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(upload = if_else(date < upload_date, "Historical","forecast"))
```

The output will look like this.

```
> upload_date
[1] "2018-02-22"

> df
        date     upload
1 2017-01-01 Historical
2 2019-01-01   forecast
```

I'd check out the free [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) book for some basic operations on data frames.

Comment: I posted my code above, but it returns a warning message: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(date, upload_date) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: *‘<’ not meaningful for factors* means that somewhere along the line "date" and/or "upload_data" has been converted to factors rather than date objects. You should convert them to date in the ```mutate()``` before you generate the upload variable.

```mutate(date = ymd(date),
                upload_date = ymd(upload_date),
                upload = if_else(date < upload_date, "Historical","forecast"))```

Comment: @divibisan implementing this code results in another warning of:    'Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. '

Comment: First try converting them to character before parsing: ```date = ymd(as.character(date))```.  If that doesn't work, look at what  ```date``` and ```upload_date``` actually look like and make sure you're using the right function to parse them. ```ymd()`` from ```lubridate``` assumes that the date is in YYYY-MM-DD format. If the dates are formatted differently you will need to use different functions to parse them.